# Timer is offset after first few executions

Tags: java

I'm using a timer with the following code

```
    if (System.currentTimeMillis () - timer > 100) { 
        timer += 100; 
        draw = !draw; 
    }
    if (draw) { 
        drawTexture (1, 15, getX() + 10, getY() + 5); 
    }
```

For the first few executions the texture is drawn at a consistent rate. Every execution is extending the time. But what's being printed doesn't change?

Render Method (Every loop)

```
public void render (double delta) {
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glViewport (0, 0, Engi.config.width, Engi.config.height);
        glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity ();
        glOrtho (0.0, Engi.config.width, Engi.config.height, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0);
        glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity ();
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
        glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glLoadIdentity ();

        if (System.currentTimeMillis () - timer > 100) { 
            timer += 100; 
            draw = !draw; 
        }
        if (draw) { 
            drawTexture (1, 15, getX() + 10, getY() + 5); 
        }

        glfwSwapBuffers (Engi.config.windowID);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the full code please? Or at least a minimal, compact, verifiable example?

Comment: I've edited your code for readability. Please do not compress your code needlessly as you're doing as that makes it hard to read and hard to understand. Use adequate new lines and whitespace (although don't overuse this either) as per Java standards.

Comment: Timer increments by 100 each time, and the System clock increments by more. So each loop will be could take more than 100ms. Plus this looks very susceptible to having quick executions in succession, if the System clock used over 200ms in one execution. edit: Draw is toggled in the timer check routine?

Comment: Yes as you can see above, it's checking if 100 ms has gone by since the last and toggles draw.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how often this code is being run.  The value returned by System.currentTimeMillis() is only updated on a system clock tick interval, which for Windows is generally 15ms.  So if you're calling this in a tight loop, timer is increasing at a very fast rate, where currentTimeMillis() is only updating every 15 msec.  Perhaps you want to just delay (Thread.sleep(long)) and then determine whether to draw.

Comment: Wouldn't this pause the whole of the application on that thread?

Comment: Yes, so you may want to do this in a separate thread.  If you're doing this in a tight loop, then the thread is still doing nothing useful, but is consuming needless CPU cycles.